# Avoiding Google Sandbox effect by redirecting an old domain to a new one

Tags: domains, redirects, google-sandbox

I believe in the Google Sandbox effect. I've seen it with a site of mine. That's why I'm now booking many domains in advance and losing money.

Since a 301 redirect from a domain to another domain almost keeps the PR, link juice, and domain age, can't we use this technique to mitigate against the Google sandbox effect?

I have several idle domains that are years old. Just today I've booked a new domain and launched a site. Can't I simply forward any old domain to this new one to make Google to pass domain age etc to my new domain to help it come out of Google sandbox?

Comment: If you forward an old domain then whats the point in registering a new domain? if the old domains are not ranking well, or have existing penguin and panda slaps then these will be passed to the new domain, not all sites go into sandbox and varies from niche, and many other factors can trigger it like dirty links and too many links to fast.

Comment: I mean parked domains in which I never hosted any website. It could be unrelated domain though. For example a 5 year old (unused) domain name railrailexample.com pointing to my newly booked domain.

Comment: As far as I know old domains have no effect on the sandbox but what does help is back links so if old domains have back links then this can trigger it to come out, but if you have a completely unrelated domain then your only passing dirty non-relevant links, the best way to get new sites out of sandbox is 'only' create superb backlinks that are relevant to the niche your targeting.

Answer (score 2):

301 redirects to a new domain are expected by Google, but "link spamming" is something they want to exclude. Reports seem to indicate that a new domain may temporarily benefit from the indexed age of redirected domains, but eventually will be evaluated on its own merits as Google learns your site, so the benefit is lost.

They don't openly acknowledging the widely debated "Sandbox Effect", but it is clear they're attempting to limit PR manipulation, so multiple redirects will likely not help your new site over time.

As far as losing money on registered domains, if they're generating traffic then you'll benefit from that if you redirect them to your new domain.

As far as getting out of the "Sandbox", the solution would be to improve the quality of the site's content and links from authoritative related sites so that it can be evaluated better.

Comment: Sorry I mean to say that I want to redirect from unused parked domains only in which I've never hosted any website for years. Such domain will not contain any history for ranking purpose.

Comment: 301 redirects from unused, non-indexed domains shouldn't have any impact (or benefit).